# i cannot start mysql (i use both xampp and appserve)

Tags: mysql, xampp, appserver

I need to use Xampp & Appserve but I don't use mqsql of Xampp.

I try to stop mysql in service and change port from 3306 > 3307

but it is still not resolved.

What should I do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seams your mysqld still tries to connect to the default port 3306.
Try to delect the mysql.sock file and restart the service.